# Fetch Product By ID Using Getx Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, flutter-getx

My app his two  Screens  Home and Details, I'm successfully fetching products and rendering them on the Home page.
also with help of getx arguments, I'm passing the ID of each Product to Detail  Screen on Navigation successfully.

what I'm trying to  Do is fetch the exact product Using his ID.

Here is  my  controller :

```
var  mealDet =  new Meal().obs;

void fetchMealByID({String  id})async{
try{
  var meal = await  RemoteServices.fetchMealById(id);
  if(meal !=  null){
    mealDet.map((data) => meal);
  }
}finally{
  isLoading =false;
}
```

on Details Screen :

```
final ProductController myController = Get.find();
final   String id   = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

I tried to  access `mealDet` using  controller  instance ,But  nothing  went right

Answer (score 1):

You need a different way of handling updates in your custom models (e.g. `Meal`). So you may have to use `mealDet.update` method as mentioned [here](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md#note-about-lists).

In your specific case, in order to update your `Meal` class you can use :

```
...
if(meal !=  null){
  mealDet.update((m){
    m.map((data) => meal);
  }
}
...
```